# Configure Apache to rewrite API calls

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-15.04

I have a project constisting of two parts. First, the API, where all data requests are handled. Second, a web client, so that users can use the tool conveniently. The web client therefore just makes API calls.

The project structure is the following:

```
/var/www
    /myproject
        /api
            /v1
                Controller.php /* this is the API v1 controller */
        /webclient
            /views /* just some templates ... */
            /public /* all public stuff, like css, html, images, ... */
                index.php /* index file for web client */
```

I configured Apache to have `/var/www/myproject/webclient/public` as document root, and I had an `Alias` so that calls to `myproject.host.loc/api/v1/Controller.php?<much-params>` would be redirected to `/var/www/myproject/api/v1`.

I now wanted to have 'prettier' API calls, like:

`myproject.host.loc/api/v1/add-item?name=fubar&api-key=4234&token=6344`

Instead of:

`myproject.host.loc/api/v1/Controller.php?request=add-item&name=fubar&api-key=4234&token=6344`

Therefore, I wanted to map every URI which requests `/api/v1` to `Controller.php` and let the script do the rest. I don't want any other resource or script in `/var/www/myproject/api/v1` to be accessed directly.

I tried to do that with the following Apache virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject/webclient/public
    ServerName myproject.host.loc

    Alias /api/v1 /var/www/myproject/api/v1
    <Directory /var/www/myproject/api/v1>
        RewriteBase    /api/v1/
        RewriteEngine  On
        RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule    api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/Controller.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The webclient shows up, but the intended way I would like to call the API does not work. If I open `myproject.host.loc/api/v1` in the browser, it just shows me the `Index of /api/v1`, containing every file. It seems like the rewrite rule is completely ignored. I can also access the API in the 'old' way, but I want to replace it with the new, 'prettier' call. (Also for security reasons, so that only the controller is callable from the outside)

How can I accomplish this? I tried several ways to do so, including:

- Completely remove `Alias` and replace it with `Rewrite`. This resulted in infinite loops or I would have to use the webclient with the URL `myproject.host.loc/webclient/public`...
- With or without `RewriteBase`. Seems like this is ignored, too. Does not change anything
- Appended or removed every trailing `/` in any possible combination. (I was desperate)

While searching for a solution, I have found a resource where someone says, that you can't use `Alias` with `Rewrite`, but I have also found people saying that it is possible... I am quite confused now.

I hope someone can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem:

```
        RewriteBase    /api/v1/
        RewriteRule    api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/Controller.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Remember that `RewriteBase` is prepended to the condition in the `RewriteRule`. So you've asked for rewriting URLs that begin with `/api/v1/api/v1/`.

Simply remove the duplication.

Comment: You are right, that seems to be the issue. But it does not work as expected. If I call `myproject.host.loc/api/v1/`, it shows the `Index of` again, with all files visible. And it does not work when I change `RewriteBase` to `/` and leave the `RewriteRule` as it is... Why does it not work? I get a 404 then